# Web config Error when using browser only

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, iis-6

I have a website that is setup in the IIS as an application on a server. When i click a page from the IIS and click browse it loads the page fine. If i run the web app in VS2010, it launches the pages just fine. The problem is when i try to access the page from a browser it gives me this error...

> Configuration Error  Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 88:             ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
Line 89:         -->
Line 90:     <authentication mode="Windows" />
Line 91:     <!--
Line 92:             The <customErrors> section enables configuration
```

This is site is totally down due to this error and i need to get it fixed asap...google has yielded 2 results, make sure the site is set as an app in IIS which it is and also check for nested web.config files which there is only one config file. Thoughts?

Comment: Double check that your virtual directory is really an application in IIS. 9/10 times that's why this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a web.config in a sub-folder of a website that is not configured as an IIS application.  You have to either make that folder a proper application, or remove that web.config file.

So for example:  Your website is in: `C:\inetpub\mysite`, and you have: `c:\inetpub\mysite\subfolder1\web.config`.  In order for that web.config to be accepted by IIS, you have to tell IIS that `subfolder1` is an IIS application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also converted the folder you are trying to protect as a web application within IIS?  Right click on the folder inside of IIS and select Convert to Application.